# Redirecting log4j statements to custom console in java

Tags: java, logging, log4j

The following class uses a JInternalFrame holding a Textarea that displays all the redirected println and err statements.

```
public class ConsoleFrame extends JInternalFrame
{
  JTextArea outArea = new JTextArea(10,100);
  static JInternalFrame cons;
  public ConsoleFrame() 
  {
    outArea.setLineWrap(true);
    JScrollPane pain = new JScrollPane(outArea);
    //pain.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    this.add(pain);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(1000,400); 
    this.setTitle("Groovy Console");
    this.closable = false;
    this.maximizable = false;
    this.isSelected = true;
    this.resizable = false;
    BasicInternalFrameUI ui = (BasicInternalFrameUI)this.getUI();
    Component north = ui.getNorthPane();
    MouseMotionListener[] actions =
    (MouseMotionListener[])north.getListeners(MouseMotionListener.class);

    for (int i = 0; i < actions.length; i++)
    north.removeMouseMotionListener( actions[i] );

    this.setFocusable(false);    
 //logger
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(new JTextAreaOutputStream(outArea)));
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new JTextAreaOutputStream(outArea)));

    setConsole(this);
  }


  static public JInternalFrame getConsole(){
      return cons;
  }
  public void setConsole(JInternalFrame console){
      cons = console;
  }
  public class JTextAreaOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    JTextArea ta;

    public JTextAreaOutputStream(JTextArea t) {
      super();
      ta = t;
    }

    public void write(int i) {
      ta.append(Character.toString((char)i));
    }

    public void write(char[] buf, int off, int len) {
      String s = new String(buf, off, len);
      ta.append(s);
    }

  }

}
```

This class only redirects the sysout and syserr statements. What modification should I make in the code to redirect the logger statements into the textarea?

Comment: Which logging framework are you using? The built-in Java one? Log4J?

Comment: If you are using log4j, look into the console appender.

Comment: is there a reason you are creating two streams instead of one?

Comment: Check this blog [TextAreaAppender](http://textareaappender.zcage.com/) Hope it helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should implement a custom Log4J logger. There are very useful base classes to extend from. I would recommend using a `org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender`.

Answer (score 2):

The Log4J logger is probably getting its references to System.out and System.err before you replace them. So you can either implement a custom Appender, or try to beat Log4J to the punch. The latter may be possible if you have control of startup.

Comment: Sinec log4j usually gets configured very early in the application startup, I don't think thats feasible. And it would only work if there is a ConsoleAppender configured in Log4J. But since the asker also wants to redirect his Standard streams, he might as well do this before app startup. So +1

Comment: @Daniel in general I agree, but in this case, it is a UI application, so I figured @VeeKay had these options.